# How can I add @EnableFeignClients

Tags: spring-boot, feign, openfeign

I added the feign dependency in the pomxml, and added the dependency manager accordingly. Why can I not add the @EnableFeignClients?

I tried to do what i described before, but i cannot figure out why it doesn't work. Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by saying it doesn't work? Your IDE don't suggest it in auto complete feature or you get compilation error?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that, you have used the correct dependency and update maven/pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

It requires no more than this dependency (which includes @EnableFeignClients annotation) should be available.

You can use maven cli to update pom as well:

```
mvn clean install
```